# Problem with calculating day difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, dayjs

Hello I have a problem with calculating difference between two dates using dayjs.
My code looks like this:

```js
const isPeriodLongerThanNinetyDays = (timestamp) => {
    const dateOfFeedbackFormatted = dayjs(timestamp).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    const actualDate = dayjs();
    const dateOfFeedback = dayjs(dateOfFeedbackFormatted);
    const dateDifference = actualDate.diff(dateOfFeedback, 'day')
    return dateDifference;
}
```

I'm missing out something because this method returns NaN everytime instead of number and I don't know why.

Comment: Did you try without `format('DD/MM/YYYY')`? And format it after you get difference

Comment: No i had not. Gonna check this out

Comment: Ok so I'll convert it to answer so someone else could find it easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you tried to perform `diff` on a formatted date.
Just delete `.format('DD/MM/YYYY')`
If you need to format it - do it after `diff`

```js
const isPeriodLongerThanNinetyDays = (timestamp) => {
    const dateOfFeedback = dayjs(timestamp);
    const actualDate = dayjs();
    const dateDifference = actualDate.diff(dateOfFeedback, 'day')
    return dateDifference.format('DD/MM/YYYY');
}
```